# Twitter: list of people I am following that do not follow me back!

Tags: twitter, twitter-integration

I know there are a lot of unfollow tools out there, but what I need is a way to sort out a list of the people I am following that do not follow me back.

I then want to add those in a private list, so that I can target them.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: There are tons of tools to do this... Otherwise you can automate it with your own API script.

Answer (score 1):

There is no official way to get the list of people who are not following you back. You have to check it manually and add (or remove) them into (from) lists.

Click on **Following** on your profile. Whoever is following you back, next to their handle `Follows you` will be written. Others are not following you back, add them into your private list one by one.

There are so many [third party tools](https://www.internetmarketingninjas.com/blog/social-media/4-tools-see-who-isnt-following-back-twitter/) you check them at your own risk*.

<sup>*I have not used any of these tools.</sup>